# How to streamline the Azure Resource Groups

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

Not long ago,  I started to research Azure Resource Manager and all that it involves. The main goal is to deploy a VM with access to SQL database. Now I'm still trying to work on deploying azure sample templates using this guide: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/getting-started-with-azure-resource-manager-and-azure-deployment-part-iii

But my question relates specifically to the Azure Resource Groups. Lets say I have a couple of resource groups each containing one resource (according to the Azure architecture). Can I somehow streamline them? Maybe using tags? And if so, how to accomplish that?

Comment: Just to clarify this questions is about Azure Stack and not Azure?

Comment: I'm using Azure portal and Azure Resource Manager to manage Azure resources.

Comment: What do you mean by stream line, do you mean to consolidate resources from multiple resource groups in to a single resource group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of Azure Resource Groups has a number of benefits. One of them is the possibility of applying tags. So you can safely tag your resources with the value pairs to categorize and view them within the portal. You just simply use the Browse hub to view Everything and select Tags.

Besides, you can collect usage per Resource Group and grant access to both users groups (Role Based Access Control (RBAC)). More info on this: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-sql-databases-api-management-media-services-websites-role-based-access-control-and-more

Hope it helps!